# Как узнать имеет ли в себе div id="id" дочерние элементы

Tags: jquery

На странице изначально записано `<div id="id"></div>`,
но я могу туда поместить кое-какой контент позже, вот так `$id.html(data.id);`.
Как проверить внесены ли внутрь дочерние элементы?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function isEmpty(el) {
    return !$.trim(el.html())
  }
  if (isEmpty($('#id'))) {
    console.log('Пусто!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id"></div>
```

или вот так

```
if($.trim($("#id").html())=='')
```

на самом деле есть чуть проще, но там проблемы с пробелами всякими могут быть

```
if ($('#id').is(':empty')){
  console.log('Пусто!');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно использовать `$id.children().length`

Вернет количество непосредственных потомков.